# How to implode a mysql query result array

Tags: implode

I am running an SQL query which returns 18 results then I try to implode them. When I use the implode command right after `mysqli_fetch_array` to implode the `mysqli_fetch_array` result, I get only the first element of the array. However when I do the same with a while loop it works fine.

Here is my code: (it's simplified for ease of understanding)

```
$q = "SELECT id from sr WHERE m_id = '4';";
$my_query = mysqli_query($conn, $q); 

$records = mysqli_num_rows($my_query); 
echo 'records=' . $records;

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($my_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r ($result);

$imploded_result = implode(",", $result);
echo 'imploded_result=' . $imploded_result;
```

Here is what I get:

```
records=14
Array ( [id] => 14 )
imploded_result=14
```

Now, when I use a while loop instead of the implode(), I get the correct results:

```
$imploded_result = '';
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($my_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
     $imploded_result .= $result['id'] . ',';
echo 'imploded_result=' . $imploded_result;
```

I get:

```
imploded_result=14,21,24,27,28,30,31,32,37,152,155,154,156,157,158,159,181,196,
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches only one record out of the result set. So put each id into an array inside the loop, and implode it after.

Comment: Or use `mysqli_fetch_all`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs to get a similar outcome. I decided to use GROUP_CONCAT in my query line. So I changed my query line from:

```
$q = "SELECT id from sr WHERE m_id = '4';";
```

to:

```
$q = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS id from sr WHERE m_id = '4';";
```

which will give me my desired outcome.